# Office 365 Home Premium Installaion Errors

Tags: windows-8, installation, microsoft-office, office365

This is a brand new Lenovo convertible with Windows 8.

It came with Office 2010 starter pack. It was never used however. I went ahead and bought Office 365 Home Premium. However, the Office 365 click-to-install is unable to install the application at all. I have already spent a couple of evenings on it.

Initially, it gave a message that said I don't have an Internet connection or enough space on the hard drive. Both were untrue as such. Then I looked here and there and uninstalled the Office Starter pack.

It now says "We found a pre-release or Beta version of an Office product on your computer and can't install because of it" blah blah blah. It also takes me to a MS webpage where it offers FixIt tool that removes the stuff. I already did that a few times.

Even then it gives the same message. So I went ahead with manual removal process listed on the website and did everything it said.

And still I get the same error message "We found a pre-release or Beta....". I refreshed the Windows 8 to get rid of every program that I installed. Then repeated the whole process but the problem continues.

I am totally stuck and don't know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Have you created your Microsoft account? Have you registered 365 with Microsoft and does it show as available for download?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a full reset (not refresh) of the PC (back up your files first) and start again. Ignore the office 2010 that is installed as it shouldn't affect your installation of 365 and can sometimes actually speed it up (no logic to it, just what I have found from installing 365 a fair few times).

Log into your Microsoft account and start the download again.

Something important to point out - when installing 365, you will occasionally see your screen looking like nothing is happening (you see no sign of 365 at all) and it is very tempting to try again because you don't think it is working/doing anything. Just leave it. Don't restart the download or anything. I have seen this last half hour or more in some cases! When you try re-download and start again, it messes up the office installation completely which is what I suspect has happened to you.